# Printing the average of floats from a list that contains both floats and strings

Tags: python, list

I'm performing sentiment analysis on Tweets I've collected, and each outcome looks like this, depending on the amount of tweets:

```
['pos', 0.8, 'neg', 1.0, 'pos', 1.0, 'pos', 1.0, 'pos', 1.0, 'pos', 1.0, 'neg', 1.0]
```

The floats stand for the confidence%, and I want to calculate & print the average of all of them from this list, but I'm having quite some trouble with it.

Comment: Are you trying to find the average of the entire confidence values, or for each sentiment?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Average of the entire confidence values, my code already prints the total % of negative and positive Tweets, I just want the overall average confidence level per outcome as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
A = ['pos', 0.8, 'neg', 1.0, 'pos', 1.0, 'pos', 1.0, 'pos', 1.0, 'pos', 1.0, 'neg', 1.0]  

res = sum(A[1::2]) / (len(A) / 2)

print(res)

0.9714285714285714
```

Or if you would rather not create a new list:

```
from itertools import islice

res = sum(islice(A, 1, None, 2)) / (len(A) / 2)
```

Alternatively, you can use `statistics.mean`, also in the standard library:

```
from statistics import mean

res = mean(A[1::2])
```